# Calcular el área de un polígono encerrado para topografia

Tags: android

Buenas comunidad, he venido por ayuda ya que he deseado calcular el área de unos datos topográficos aunque no he podido calcular aunque lo he tratado de hacer pero no me dan los cálculos. Aquí dejare la teoría para ver si me pueden ayudar con los dos métodos para calcularlo.

[image: Método para calcular el área del polígono]

[image: Área del polígono]

Comment: Disculpa, pero en que lenguaje de programación lo estas haciendo? Es bueno que lo dejes como titulo, ya que no se entiende

Comment: y aunque no te haya salido, pon el codigo. Capaz podemos detectar el error.

Answer (score 0):

Intente resolverlo y me dio el resultado pero de una manera algo larga, si existiera una manera mas accesible seria genial, pero seguramente eso seria creando una función. Y pude resolver con determinantes.

[image: Aplicando determinantes]